# Convert Flatten layer from PyTorch to Tensorflow - Equivalent for start_dim and end_dim

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, flatten

What is the equivalent of the options `start_dim` and `end_dim` of the `flatten` PyTorch layers, in Tensorflow?

With Tensorlfow we only have `data_format` and it is not customizable.

Comment: In `Flatten` layer in tensorflow, it is always `start_dim=1` and `end_dim=-1`. If you want to flatten other dimensions, you may use `Reshape` layer. Red about reshape [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Reshape).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an identical implementation in `tf`. However, you can always use `tf.reshape` and add the shape yourself with a simple function which takes as arguments `input`, `start_dim` and `end_dim` and outputs the corresponding output `shape` that `torch.flatten` would give you.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, I used the reshape layer !